ImportError: No module named psycopg2 from s3
Working with AWS Glue with Terraform I could not get psycopg2 to import into my Glue Job
I added it's whl from s3 to --additional-python-modules and it still didn't work
I tried adding pyscopg2 to be install with its version number as well into the key but it didnt work
The job was initially made on Glue version 4 with python3 runtime

The way to resolve the issue is to with Glue version 4 add in the console-> job detgails -> python library path: the whl's for pg8000, asn1crypto, importlib_metadata, after you download them and put them into an s3 bucket.
It's better to use pg8000 over psycopg2 because the latter is made from C which Glue struglles with pg8000 works better but also need importlib_metadata and asn1crypto downloaded as dependencies.
The format of the two libraries is also pretty interchanagable so you'll largely just have to change the call and none of the logic

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
